# Why is my nested model failing to be created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created what should be a simple many to one relationship on Rails 4.1.0.beta

Item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :sales
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sales
  validates_presence_of :category, :owner, :name, :description
end
```

Sale.rb

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :bids
  validates_presence_of :item, :seller
end
```

These are the relevant tables in the database according to schema.rb

```
  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
  create_table "sales", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "seller_id"
    t.integer  "buy_it_now"
    t.boolean  "bidding_enabled"
    t.integer  "minimum_starting_bid"
    t.string   "currency"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

In the rails console when I try to create a Sale nested inside of an Item like this:

```
> params = {"item"=>{"owner_id"=>"3", "category_id"=>"1", "name"=>"fawkin item", "description"=>"blarg", "sales_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"seller_id"=>"3", "buy_it_now"=>"5", "bidding_enabled"=>"0", "minimum_starting_bid"=>"", "currency"=>"btc"}}}}
> item = Item.new(params["item"])
> item.sales.first
```

The resulting sale entry inside of item.sales is missing an item_id:

```
#<Sale id: nil, item_id: nil, seller_id: 3, buy_it_now: 5, bidding_enabled: false, minimum_starting_bid: nil, currency: "btc", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

And if I try to save item, the transaction rolls back:

```
> item.save
> item.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000013bfc58 @base=#<Item id: nil, owner_id: 3, category_id: 1, name: "fawkin item", description: "blarg", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:"sales.item"=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

Comment: How does your controller looks like? Have you modyfied the private controller action which permits the attributes, to allow also the nested ones?

Comment: I have, but by doing it in the console, I've also nullified any effect strong parameters would have.

Comment: Shouldn't "base" model be saved first? You get no `item_id` in related (`Sale`) because `item` doesn't have one until it's saved to DB.

Comment: what´s about Item.new.sales.build before creating all together?

Answer (score 0):

Sales is dependent on Items. you can't create a sales record without the item existing first. It's a two-step process, you can't lump it all in one method call like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one simple application with nested attribute it worked for me.
Please look in to the code which is available at [nested attribute example](https://github.com/amit4m2008/survay)